# Mysqli - Commands out of sync

Tags: mysqli, php

Использую mysqli для обращения к БД (php).

При выполнении очередного запроса возвращает следующую ошибку:

> Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now in your client code

Поиски в интернете мне сказали, что стоит очистить результаты предыдущего выполнения. Но, последний запрос у меня был: `$mysqli->multi_query(...)` который выполняет несколько UPDATE, и в результате он возвращает только true и очистка не помогает.

Запрос, на котором выходит ошибка - SELECT, который отдельно выполняется без проблем.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну [доки](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) же, первый коммент:

```
while ($mysqli->next_result()) {;} // flush multi_queries
```

Comment: а, кажется понял, спасибо ) как-то упустил этот цикл, всё зациклился на `$result->free();` )